# How can I schedule a python script which uses a file that is in the same directory with cron?

Tags: python, cron

```
FILE_NAME = 'last_seen_id.txt'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. My script use that file and I can only execute it from terminal when I'm in the same directory.
So p.e **python3 Documentos/my_bot/my_twitter_bot.py** won't work from /home.

So I assume that ***/5 * * * * python3 /home/david/Documentos/my_bot/my_twitter_bot.py** in my crontab won't work either.

What should I do? Pass the file as a parameter? Is there other way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use the absolute path to file in your script.

Option 2: make cron first go to the desired directory, and then run the script

```
*/5 * * * * cd home/david/Documentos/my_bot && python3 my_twitter_bot.py
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought you could do that but I didn't know how.